# Why using logarithmic gives 8e+2 value?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using a `chart` and I am using `type: 'logarithmic',` passing the `max value` like this:

```
max: scalesMax.toFixed(2),
```

But that gives me `8e+2`

How can I fix it?

I'm using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)

This how I get my values for each charts, I have one chart next to the other to compare each values form 2 datasets

```
var scalesMaxTotalCasesTrend = Math.max(...customConfirmed);
var scalesMaxTotalPositiveTrend = Math.max(...totPositivi);    
var scalesMaxIsolationTrend = Math.max(...totIsolamento);     
var scalesMaxHospitalizationTrend = Math.max(...totRicoverati);
var scalesMaxHospitalizationWithSymptomsTrend = Math.max(...totRicoveratiConSintomi);
var scalesMaxIntensiveCareTrend = Math.max(...totTerapiaIntensiva);

function setConfigurationGraph(dataGraphType, labels, data, scalesMax) {
    configAllDateGraph.push({
        dataGraphType: dataGraphType,
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(250, 250, 250, 1)",
                data: data,
                borderColor: "#fafafa",
                borderDash: [5, 5],
                backgroundColor: "#fafafa",
                pointBackgroundColor: "#fafafa",
                pointBorderColor: "#fafafa",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fafafa",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "#fafafa"
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "#fafafa"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "#fafafa"
                    }
                }],

                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    type: 'logarithmic',
                    gridLines: {
                        color: "#fafafa"
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: "#fafafa",
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        max: scalesMax.toFixed(2),
                        min: 0
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What chart plugin are you talking about? Please show your code.

Comment: @Barmar updated the question with more code, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This automatically happens in JS i believe. 
You can use `toFixed()` max limit of 20; 
Have you tried this

`max: scalesMax.toFixed(20)`

Comment: oh, no didn't try it. Yet chart.js 3 which we can get on git, resolved this